# Title not hiding when change dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I got stuck when I change role job from all roles to engineering all table not in engineering class hide, but when I choose to analyst role, title in table analyst not showing instead engineering title always show when change each dropdown.

```js
$("select.filterby").change(function() {
  var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e) {
 return $(e).val();
  }).join(".");
  var engineering = $("div#FilterContainer").find("h3, .third-title, .engineering, tr").hide();
  var analyst = $("div#FilterContainer").find("h3, .third-title, .analyst, tr").hide();

  if (analyst) {
 $("div#FilterContainer").find("h3.third-title.engineering, tr." + filters).show();
  } else if (engineering) {
 $("div#FilterContainer").find("h3.third-title.analyst, tr." + filters).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="FilterContainer" class="container">
    <h3 class="third-title all engineering">Engineering</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="">
          <table class="table">
            <tr class="all engineering technology full_time jakarta">
              <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="fe-dev.html">Front End Developer</a></td>
              <td>Technology</td>
              <td>Full time</td>
              <td>Jakarta</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="all engineering technology intern jakarta">
              <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="fe-in-dev.html">Front End Developer</a></td>
              <td>Technology</td>
              <td>Intern</td>
              <td>Jakarta</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="all engineering technology full_time jakarta">
              <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="wp-dev.html">Wordpress Developer</a></td>
              <td>Technology</td>
              <td>Full time</td>
              <td>Jakarta</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="all engineering technology full_time jakarta">
              <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="ad-dev.html">Android Developer</a></td>
              <td>Technology</td>
              <td>Full time</td>
              <td>Jakarta</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="all engineering technology full_time jakarta">
              <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="ios-dev.html">IOS Developer</a></td>
              <td>Technology</td>
              <td>Full time</td>
              <td>Jakarta</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="all engineering technology full_time jakarta">
              <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="be-dev.html">Back End Developer</a></td>
              <td>Technology</td>
              <td>Full time</td>
              <td>Jakarta</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="all engineering technology intern jakarta">
              <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="be-in-dev.html">Back End Developer</a></td>
              <td>Technology</td>
              <td>Intern</td>
              <td>Jakarta</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="third-title all analyst">Analyst</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="">
          <table class="table">
            <tr class="all analyst technology full_time jakarta">
              <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="sa.html">System Analyst</a></td>
              <td>Technology</td>
              <td>Full time</td>
              <td>Jakarta</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="all analyst technology intern jakarta">
              <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="sa-in.html">System Analyst</a></td>
              <td>Technology</td>
              <td>Intern</td>
              <td>Jakarta</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I had try to create if else if condition which is I declare analyst and engineering as parameter then hide title of each section analyst and engineering.

Updated.

```
<select class="form-control filterby">
  <option value="all">All roles</option>
  <option value="accounting">Accounting</option>
  <option value="administrative">Administrative</option>
  <option value="analyst">Analyst</option>
  <option value="engineering">Engineering</option>
  <option value="product">Product</option>
  <option value="marketing_sales">Marketing and Sales</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Where is `select.filterby` in your HTML?

Comment: Wait, I put it on select class="filterby"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code. Try and check:

```js
$("select.filterby").change(function() {
  $("div#FilterContainer").find("h3,tr").hide();
  $("div#FilterContainer").find("h3." + $(this).val() + ",tr." + $(this).val()).show();
  
  $("#no-result-container").hide();
  if($("div#FilterContainer").find("h3." + $(this).val() + ",tr." + $(this).val()).length == 0) {
    $("#no-result-container").show();
  }
});
```

```css
#no-result-container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control filterby">
  <option value="all">All roles</option>
  <option value="accounting">Accounting</option>
  <option value="administrative">Administrative</option>
  <option value="analyst">Analyst</option>
  <option value="engineering">Engineering</option>
  <option value="product">Product</option>
  <option value="marketing_sales">Marketing and Sales</option>
</select>
<div id="FilterContainer" class="container">
  <div id="no-result-container" class="container"> No search parameter in here.</div>
  <h3 class="third-title all engineering">Engineering</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="">
        <table class="table">
          <tr class="all engineering technology full_time jakarta">
            <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="fe-dev.html">Front End Developer</a></td>
            <td>Technology</td>
            <td>Full time</td>
            <td>Jakarta</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="all engineering technology intern jakarta">
            <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="fe-in-dev.html">Front End Developer</a></td>
            <td>Technology</td>
            <td>Intern</td>
            <td>Jakarta</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="all engineering technology full_time jakarta">
            <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="wp-dev.html">Wordpress Developer</a></td>
            <td>Technology</td>
            <td>Full time</td>
            <td>Jakarta</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="all engineering technology full_time jakarta">
            <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="ad-dev.html">Android Developer</a></td>
            <td>Technology</td>
            <td>Full time</td>
            <td>Jakarta</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="all engineering technology full_time jakarta">
            <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="ios-dev.html">IOS Developer</a></td>
            <td>Technology</td>
            <td>Full time</td>
            <td>Jakarta</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="all engineering technology full_time jakarta">
            <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="be-dev.html">Back End Developer</a></td>
            <td>Technology</td>
            <td>Full time</td>
            <td>Jakarta</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="all engineering technology intern jakarta">
            <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="be-in-dev.html">Back End Developer</a></td>
            <td>Technology</td>
            <td>Intern</td>
            <td>Jakarta</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3 class="third-title all analyst">Analyst</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="">
        <table class="table">
          <tr class="all analyst technology full_time jakarta">
            <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="sa.html">System Analyst</a></td>
            <td>Technology</td>
            <td>Full time</td>
            <td>Jakarta</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="all analyst technology intern jakarta">
            <td style="width: 300px;"><a href="sa-in.html">System Analyst</a></td>
            <td>Technology</td>
            <td>Intern</td>
            <td>Jakarta</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain me what is exactly this code do?
`$(this).val() + ",tr." + $(this).val()`

Comment: So we are using elements together and writing them in single line instead of writing them separately. Individually, it would have been `"h3." + $(this).val()` and `"tr." + $(this).val()`. By using comma, we converted into one line. And `$(this).val()` is the value selected from the dropdown, and that value is the `class` name for `h3` and `tr`.

Comment: Okay, but how this code `$(this).val()` take value selected from dropdown, instead I use `var filters = ....` then declare `return $(e).val();` then insert filterby class in each select dropdown in HTML?

Comment: So inside the `change` event on the function, we will always have `$(this).val()` as the current selected value. So we don't need to use `map`, `toArray` or `filters`.

Comment: You're welcome. You can up-vote it. Happy Coding!! :)

Comment: What if I want to show some text that show "No search parameter in here"? `$("div#FilterContainer").find("h2." + $(this).val() + ",tr." + $(this).val()).addClass("result");` I was doing that, and add `no-result` class in html file

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I have updated the code by adding a container (`no-result-container`) that would be displayed if there are no results.

Comment: Thank you again dude. Are you enroll some course for jquery or another javascript framework? Maybe you can suggest me where I can learn it? I also read about w3schools, but I think I more comfort with video tutorial.

Comment: I learnt online watching videos too. Here is where you can start and where I started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNb8T5NBdQg&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810